# Check if bean is managed by spring or JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, javabeans

Does it possible to check programatically if bean is managed by spring or JSF?

Comment: You could ask the spring application context for a certain bean and check the result.

Comment: https://spring.io/understanding/application-context

Answer (score -1):

I have a class:

```
public class ContextHelper  {

// this method print all managed beans by spring container
public static void printManagedBeans(ApplicationContext ctx) {

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();

    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        ColorConsoleHelper.getGreenLog("bean is managed by spring " +     beanName);
    }
  }
}
```

after used that class i have a result:

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor

INFO: [ok] bean is managed by spring org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor

**Why on the list is not visible beans that I marked using for example @Service annotation?** I would like to see all managed beans by spring container included my custom POJO class.